# Ошибка при отправке email средствами Python (smtplib)

Tags: python, email, smtp

Вот небольшой код:

```
import smtplib as smtp

email = '***@gmail.com'
password = '***'

dest_email = '***@gmail.com'
subject = 'My Subject'
email_text = "..."
message = 'From: {}\nTo: {}\nSubject: {}\n\n{}'.format(email, dest_email, subject, email_text)

server = smtp.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo(email)
server.login(email, password)
server.auth_plain()
server.sendmail(email, dest_email, message)
server.quit()
```

Другими словами, я пытаюсь отправить мэйл средствами Python (`smtplib`), но получаю следующие ошибки:

> reply: b'501-5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "***@gmail.com" invalid, closing\r\n'

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\IT-Service\Desktop\sendmail.py", line 14, in 
> server.login(email, password) File "C:\Users\IT-Service\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 716, in login
> raise SMTPNotSupportedError(
> smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.

В чем их причина и как их исправить?

Comment: Порт точно 587? Пароль получал из паролей приложений?

Comment: @RottenRat, `email` и `password` однозначно рабочие.  Они от действующего Gmail-аккаунта. `dest_email` тоже существует.

Comment: Нужно использовать аккаунт приложения https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=ru

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чем заключалась проблема! Просто на сегодняшний день многие фримэйл-провайдеры требуют дополнительную активацию для SMTP и POP3/IMAP...